# PostgreSQL N:N Datos en cascada

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy creando una API para un negocio local, principalmente tendré dos tablas que son productos y ventas, pero la relación de los productos con la ventas es N:N, ya que una venta puede tener muchos productos y un producto, a su vez, puede tener muchas ventas.

Para eso cree una tercera tabla que se relaciona con las otras dos, pero mi problema surge cuando quiero insertar data en cascada, es decir cada vez que se agregue una nueva venta, quiero que además se agregue la relación de esa venta con los productos asociados a ella, pero como tengo id auto incrementables no sé como hacerlo, ya que, tendría que agregar primero una venta para obtener el id y así asociarlo con los productos en la tabla de relación.

Me perdí un poco ya que hace mucho no trabajaba con relaciones, pero es un requisito del cliente y necesario.

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
id_productos SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
descripción VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL,
precio INT NOT NULL,
cantidad INT NOT NULL,
estado BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
);

CREATE TABLE ventas(
id_ventas SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
cliente VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
total INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
fecha DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);

CREATE TABLE ventas_productos(
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
venta_id int REFERENCES ventas(id_ventas)ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
producto_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES productos(id_productos) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Otra duda que tengo es como manejar el stock de los productos, es decir, hago que cada producto se repita una y otra vez y hacer un count para obtener el stock o agregarlo directamente como una columna en el producto. Creo que varios podrían darme una opción de como manejar el inventario de mejor manera.

En resumen, mis dudas son como ingresar datos relacionados en cascada con relación muchos a muchos ya que tengo id autoincrementables,  y como administrar el stock de los productos.

Comment: Me perdí pues es algo extenso y confuso el escrito, cual o cuáles son las dudas?

Comment: Intentaré editarlo para que quede más claro. Pero principalmente quiero ingresar datos en cascadas en tablas relacionadas N:N